# if $f_n$ is point wise bounded measurable sequence then it is uniformly bounded on certain sets in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

[image]

My solution:
Consider $f(x)=\sup_n|f_n(x)|$ it is finite everywhere and measurable and so, by Lusin, there is a closed set $F$ s.t $f$ is continuous on $F$ and $\mu([0,1]-F)\leq \epsilon$ Now $F$ is closed and bounded thus compact. Thus $f$ is also bounded uniformly on $F$. Which concludes the proof.

IS this correct? Are there any other nice proofs of this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is actually much simpler. There is no need to  come up with continuous functions.

Consider $A_N=\{x: \sup_n |f_n(x)| \leq N\}$. These sets increase to $[0,1]$ as $N$ increases to $\infty$ so $m(A_N) \to 1$. This implies that  $m(A_N^{c}) <\epsilon$ if $N$ is sufficiently large. Just take $A_{\epsilon} =A_N$ and $B_{\epsilon} =N$.

Comment: Why can I not apply Lusins theorem here?

Comment: Lusin's theorem does not give you a close set. @2132123

Comment: Yes it does, I am using Royden but wikipedia also agrees. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem

Comment: Your solution is much simpler though. Thank you so much, I believe it is much better to think of simpler solution's rather than using some overkill theorems.